# verificar se uma string existe em um array que esta dentro de outro array

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte variável com nome `$array` que está com os seguintes valores

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'a' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'b' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'c' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'd' (length=5)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'f' (length=6)
```

e tenho a variável com nome `$check` que está com o valor `'a'`.

Quero verificar se o valor da variável `$check` existe no *array* da variável `$array`

Já tentei com o `in_array`, mas só consigo acessar setando o número da chave dessa maneira:

```
if(in_array($check, $array[0])):
    echo "existe";
    else:
    echo "nao existe";
endif;
```

Comment: Por favor, utilizar o snippet do site apenas para códigos HTML/CSS/JS que são completos e reproduzíveis. Para PHP, utilize o `{}` do editor. Também mais atenção com as tags utilizadas, sua pergunta não tem relação alguma com HTML. Finalmente, busque escrever corretamente, incluindo as acentuações; quanto mais correto você escrever, mais fácil será a comunicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você percorrer o seu *array* e chamar a função `in_array` para cada valor:

```
function has_value($neddle, $arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        if (in_array($neddle, $value) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Agora, se a quantidade de níveis de "array de arrays" variar, você precisará fazer essa implementação de forma recursiva.